# Angular app working on Firefox/IE but not chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, amazon-web-services

I hosted my angular App on Amazon Web Services S3. It is working like a charm in Firefox and IE but not in Chrome. In console I keep receiving :

```
(index):1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
(index):1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

My index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title>Application</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700,400italic'>
    <link href="lib/angular-material/angular-material.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- js libs -->
    <script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <!-- angular material requirements -->
    <script src="lib/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-aria/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-messages/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
    <!-- angular material -->
    <script src="lib/angular-material/angular-material.min.js"></script>
    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="modules/Add/add.js"></script>
    <script src="js/all.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="Application">
    <div class="ng-main" ui-view ng-cloak></div>
</body>

</html>
```

CORS are activated! Do you have any idea? Any help would be appreciated!
PS : Locally, with npm start, it is also working on chrome without any problem!

Comment: There must be an error somewhere in your files. A directive that's not well written, it can be anything. Would you mind giving us a little bit more information or code?

Comment: seems like some invalid syntax in the html. Can you share your index.html file?

Comment: I edited my post with my index.html

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do is CTRL+MAJ+R on Chrome and it is working like a charm! Solved

Comment: What is "MAJ" in your shortcut?